# One Android Studio project uninstalls another

Tags: java, android

I have a weird problem. There are two projects, two different apps in android studio. The thing is, for some reason if I install one app and then try to install the other, the second app is somehow considered to be an "update" for the first app, so the first up gets deleted. Although those, again, are two different projects, two different apps. What could be the problem? Could you please help? Probably some weird string in the Manifest file?..

Comment: i think there is a problem with your package

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Comment: Yes, I used the same id (somehow!!) for two different programs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Android device identifies apps by their application IDs. If your projects have the same application ID, they are seemed identical.

Check your projects' `applicationId`s in the (:app) module level `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'your.app.id'
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
}
```

Avoid using the same id between different projects.